# "Failed to Save Document"

Tags: crystal-reports

So was working on a report, and attempted to `Save`, and got the "Failed to Save Document" error.

When I attempt to `Save As`, same thing happens, only  after I click `OK`, I get another pop up saying "Not Supported".

[image]

I've heard this happens when:

- You change the data source, which I did not
- When you have an error in your formulas
- When you get disconnected from the server

**What I've tried:**

- Checked my data source as being the same
- Used the X2 to check all my formulas to insure there's no error
- Made sure I was not saving data with report

**Has anyone found a solution to this issue?**

Comment: Had the same issue a couple times because my network-card disconnected and the report was stored on a network-drive. So the solution was to fix the network issue.

Comment: I hear you, could have been my issue to. But now I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve me starting the report again :/

Comment: I'm not sure, but this could maybe work: Open a new instance of crystal reports -> create a new blank report -> copy everything from your unsaved report into it -> save it!.

Comment: A bit tough. I mean, I would have to recreate each formula, running total, etc.

Comment: You can also use an older copy of your report instead of the blank one, if there is one. Most of the content like formula-content, running-totals is copied if you paste it into the new report. You can also copy multiple formulas at the same time when selecting them inside a section. Important is to first connect the database and recreate the table-links. I know, it's a workaround, but if you find a better solution, let me know. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you get that error... try this:

1. turn off save data with report.
2. save
3. turn on save data with report
4. save

after dealing with this problem for quite a while... this finally worked for me!! so happy

Comment: This didn't work for me. Changing the generated data's parameters also did nothing...